# Add dynamic data in recyclerview in another dynamic recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add recyclerview to another recyclerview.
Like Sub Category Recyclerview in its Category RecyclerViews.
problem is that I am getting All categorie's sub category item list in last item of category list.

means
Cat1
cat2
catn(then below this list of subcat1, subcat2....so on)
but it should be like cat1 then in below subcat1 and so on...

here is MainActivity code from where I am calling the api and passing adapter to recyclerview

```
private void getCategory() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, CategoryUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("DATA");
                Log.v("Cat Response", response.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    DataModel Model = new DataModel();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    catId = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                    catTitle = jsonObject.getString("TITLE");

                    Model.setTITLE(catTitle);
                    Model.setID(catId);

                    catList.add(Model);
                    categoryAdaptor.getSubCategory(catId);

                }
                categoryAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.print("Exception is :" + e.getMessage());

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}

private void setCatAdaptor() {
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
    //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
    categoryAdaptor = new CategoryAdaptor(this, catList);
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(categoryAdaptor);

}
```

here is category adapter

```
public class CategoryAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdaptor.MyViewHlder> {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<DataModel> list;
private SubCategoryAdaptor subcategoryAdaptor;
private ArrayList<SubCatModel> subCatList = new ArrayList<>();
private String SubCategoryUrl = "http://philiabeauty.com/reader-choice/controller-api.php?action=get_subcategory_by_category&id=";
private String Token = "&access_token=Ym9va19kZXRhaWxz";
private String imgRoot = "http://philiabeauty.com/reader-choice/";
private String subCatId, subCatTitle, subCatImage;

public CategoryAdaptor(Activity activity, ArrayList<DataModel> list) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHlder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_list_layout, viewGroup, false);
    MyViewHlder my = new MyViewHlder(view);

    return my;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHlder myViewHlder, int i) {

    final DataModel model = list.get(i);

    myViewHlder.catText.setText(model.getTITLE());
    myViewHlder.catId.setText(model.getID());


    setSubCatAdaptor(myViewHlder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


public void getSubCategory(String ID) {

    String SubCategoryUrlFinal = SubCategoryUrl + ID + Token;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, SubCategoryUrlFinal, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("DATA");
                Log.v("SubCat Response", response.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    SubCatModel Model = new SubCatModel();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    subCatId = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                    subCatTitle = jsonObject.getString("TITLE");
                    subCatImage = imgRoot + jsonObject.getString("IMG_SRC");
                    Model.setSubCatIMG(subCatImage);
                    Model.setSubCatTITLE(subCatTitle);
                    Model.setSubCatID(subCatId);

                    subCatList.add(Model);

                }
                subcategoryAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.print("Exception is :" + e.getMessage());

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}

private void setSubCatAdaptor(MyViewHlder myView) {
    Log.v("test", "test" );
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false);
    myView.recyclerviewSubCat.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
    //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
    subcategoryAdaptor = new SubCategoryAdaptor(activity, subCatList);
    myView.recyclerviewSubCat.setAdapter(subcategoryAdaptor);

}

class MyViewHlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView catText, viewAllBtn, catId, tag;
    private RecyclerView recyclerviewSubCat;

    public MyViewHlder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        catText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
        viewAllBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAllBtn);
        catId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_id);
        recyclerviewSubCat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSubCat);

    }
}
```

}

and here is the sub category adapter

```
public class SubCategoryAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdaptor.MyViewHlder> {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<SubCatModel> list;

public SubCategoryAdaptor(Activity activity, ArrayList<SubCatModel> list) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHlder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subcat_list, viewGroup, false);
    MyViewHlder my = new MyViewHlder(view);

    return my;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHlder myViewHlder, int i) {

    final SubCatModel model = list.get(i);

    Log.v("data", model.getSubCatTITLE());

    myViewHlder.subCatTitle.setText(model.getSubCatTITLE());
    myViewHlder.subCatId.setText(model.getSubCatID());
    String img = model.getSubCatIMG();

    Picasso.get()
            .load(img)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_book_black_24dp)
            .fit()
            .into(myViewHlder.subCatImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


class MyViewHlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView subCatTitle, subCatId, subCatTag;
    private ImageView subCatImage;

    public MyViewHlder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        subCatTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subcat_name);
        subCatId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subcat_id);
        subCatTag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subcat_tag);
        subCatImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subcat_image);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can add a `RecyclerView` in the category adapter and list the sub category items.

Comment: @Nidheesh how can i do this?

Comment: Also checkout the lib groupie ,this helps in handling complex recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the sub category adapter declaration to viewHolder,

```
public class CategoryAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdaptor.MyViewHlder> {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<DataModel> list;

    private String SubCategoryUrl = "http://philiabeauty.com/reader-choice/controller-api.php?action=get_subcategory_by_category&id=";
    private String Token = "&access_token=Ym9va19kZXRhaWxz";
    private String imgRoot = "http://philiabeauty.com/reader-choice/";
    private String subCatId, subCatTitle, subCatImage;

    public CategoryAdaptor(Activity activity, ArrayList<DataModel> list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHlder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_list_layout, viewGroup, false);
        MyViewHlder my = new MyViewHlder(view);

        return my;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHlder myViewHlder, int i) {

        final DataModel model = list.get(i);

        myViewHlder.catText.setText(model.getTITLE());
        myViewHlder.catId.setText(model.getID());


        getSubCategory(myViewHlder,model.getID());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public void getSubCategory(MyViewHlder myViewHlder,String ID) {

        String SubCategoryUrlFinal = SubCategoryUrl + ID + Token;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, SubCategoryUrlFinal, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("DATA");
                    Log.v("SubCat Response", response.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        SubCatModel Model = new SubCatModel();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        subCatId = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                        subCatTitle = jsonObject.getString("TITLE");
                        subCatImage = imgRoot + jsonObject.getString("IMG_SRC");
                        Model.setSubCatIMG(subCatImage);
                        Model.setSubCatTITLE(subCatTitle);
                        Model.setSubCatID(subCatId);

                        myViewHlder.subCatList.add(Model);

                    }
                    myViewHlder.subcategoryAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.print("Exception is :" + e.getMessage());

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }



    class MyViewHlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView catText, viewAllBtn, catId, tag;
        private RecyclerView recyclerviewSubCat;
        private SubCategoryAdaptor subcategoryAdaptor;
        private ArrayList<SubCatModel> subCatList = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyViewHlder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            catText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
            viewAllBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAllBtn);
            catId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_id);
            recyclerviewSubCat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSubCat);
            LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerviewSubCat.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
            //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
            subcategoryAdaptor = new SubCategoryAdaptor(activity, subCatList);
            recyclerviewSubCat.setAdapter(subcategoryAdaptor);

        }
    }
}
```